# Image rectification for convave shape

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a half sphere image. I'm trying to use Image rectification to transform the concave shape into flat image.
Assume we have camera parameters (focal length and lens distortions factors).

Edited: This Image [image] shows a concave shape on the table. I'm trying to remove this depth and make half sphere looks flat surface.

I've been trying to solve a problem. I'm surprised I haven't been able to find anything really useful on the net.
Where should I start to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "flatten" the hemisphere, a perpendicular view from the top and well centered is indeed better. You can develop the geometric model of this setup and this can give you the deformation equations in polar coordinates. Then write an unwarping function.

Alternatively, it is not impossible that the camera distortion parameters of the standard models will supply enough flexibility to match this deformation with sufficient accuracy. You can try it by "painting" a grid inside the hemisphere. The way to map the grid to the sphere is not unique, anyway (as there is no unique way to flatten Earth maps).

UPDATE: old answer before the OP better described the problem

That is an unusual thing you are asking. This could be called shading removal, in some way the opposite of shape-from-shading. What you see is the original color with variable luminance, depending on how it reflects the light.

To correct that, you can divide the color image by a pure luminance image. The cheap way to get it is to compute the luminance (weighted sum of RGB components) from the given image. The hard way is to synthetize a scene with a gray sphere and a gray plane using an appropriate shading model (diffuse) and knowing the light sources.

I doubt you will ever obtain a perfect correction.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that the author wanted to geometrically map the interior surface of the concave section onto a plane in order to remove distortions caused by the projection of the shape onto the sensor.

Further, dividing by the luma channel of the image would also remove texture on the surface. I think we need more information from the author before we can suggest a viable approach.

Comment: Update; see the author's comment on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Old answer before the author redefined the question.

In this example image, the concave shape does not appear to have depth to an observer because of any geometrical properties that can be extracted from intrinsic camera parameters.

Instead, the shape is concave due to the shading from the light source. You will notice that the upper left is much darker than the bottom right area within the concave area, while the rest of the background is mostly the same brightness.

These monocular vision cues are easily processed by the human brain, but can be very tricky to detect (or correct) in computer vision.

If you want to give the illusion of flatness, some sort of local operator might be usable in order to reduce or remove the difference in lightness.

However, if you wanted to extract depth information from the concave surface, and map the surface into a flat view, this task is (nearly?) impossible from a single camera view, as no extractable depth information is present.

Comment: I don't agree: this looks like a doable case for shape from shading.

Comment: @Glenn The image was not good enough to present to my issue! Imagine we capture an image for a half sphere and we want to remove the depth and map it into flat surface. you can assume that we have two images from different angles. Is it possible to map concave surface to flat surface.

Comment: Depth detection with a stereo camera system is a problem that is addressed at great depth in literature, as well as many textbooks on computer vision. In many cases, the ability to do so boils down to finding uniquely detectable points that can be used to develop a correspondence between camera views. Will the interior of these concave areas be smooth (like the one shown above) or will they have details or other features that could be recognizable by a camera?

Comment: The image has many texture features. And it is important to keep this features after the correction. The geometrical features, e.g. depth, are not so important.